# Regex Issue for Title Case on String Containing HTML Markup

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, replace, html-parsing

Currently I'm running the following replacement approach ...

```js
const str = '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:Blue;">ch</span>edilpakkam,tiruvallur';
const rex = (/(\b[a-z])/g);
 
const result = str.toLowerCase().replace(rex, function (letter) {
  //console.log(letter.toUpperCase())
  return letter.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... with a source of ...

```html
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:Blue;">ch</span>edilpakkam,tiruvallur
```

... and the following result ...

```html
<Span Style="Font-Weight:Bold;Color:Blue;">Ch</Span>Edilpakkam,Tiruvallur
```

But what I want to achieve are the following points ...

1. Bind span to string.
2. Uppercase 1st letter and word after.
3. Expected output

```html
<span style="font-weight:bold;color:Blue;">Ch</span>edilpakkam,Tiruvallur
```

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: Hi Toto, Thanks. Can you share some example @Toto

Comment: Please post the full relevant code, it is not clear how come you get `<span style='font-weight:bold;color:Blue;'>Ch</span>Edilpakkam, Tiruvallur` and not `<Span Style='Font-Weight:Bold;Color:Blue;'>Ch</Span>Edilpakkam,Tiruvallur` (that I get after running your code).

Comment: @ArunvairavanV ... are there any questions left regarding all the given answers?

Answer (score 1):

[***Toto*** already commented on the difficulties of *"parsing"* HTML code via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542932/regex-issue-for-tittle-case#comment117635268_66542932).

The following generic (markup agnostic) approach makes use of a *sandbox* like `div` element in order to benefit from its DOM parsing/accessing capabilities.

First, one needs to collect all text-nodes of the temporary sandbox. Then, for each text-node's `textContent`, one has to decide whether to start with capitalizing all words from a string's beginning or not.

The cases for [capitalizing every word within a string including the first occurring one](https://regex101.com/r/PQ1k8y/1) are ...

- The text-node's **previous sibling** either does not exist ...
- ... or is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).
- The text-node itself starts with a whitespace(-sequence).

For all other cases one wants to *capture/capitalize every first word character after a word boundary too* ... [*except for the word at the beginning of a line*](https://regex101.com/r/uPA9Ds/1).

```js
function collectContentTextNodesRecursively(list, node) {
  return list.concat(
    (node.nodeType === 1) // element-node?

    ? Array
      .from(node.childNodes)
      .reduce(collectContentTextNodesRecursively, [])

    : (node.nodeType === 3) // text-node?
      ? node
      : []
  );
}

function getNodeSpecificWordCapitalizingRegex(textNode) {
  const prevNode = textNode.previousSibling;
  const isAssumeBlockBefore = (prevNode === null) || (/^(?:address|article|aside|blockquote|details|dialog|dd|div|dl|dt|fieldset|figcaption|figure|footer|form|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|header|hgroup|hr|li|main|nav|ol|p|pre|section|table|ul)$/g).test(prevNode.nodeName.toLowerCase());

  //     either assume a previous block element, or the current text starts with whitespace.
  return (isAssumeBlockBefore || (/^\s+/).test(textNode.textContent))

    // capture every first word character after word boundary.
    ? (/\b(\w)/g)
    // capture every first word character after word boundary except at beginning of line.
    : (/(?<!^)\b(\w)/g);
}


function capitalizeEachTextContentWordWithinCode(code) {
  const sandbox = document.createElement('div');
  sandbox.innerHTML = code;

  collectContentTextNodesRecursively([], sandbox).forEach(textNode => {

    textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(
      getNodeSpecificWordCapitalizingRegex(textNode),
      (match, capture) => capture.toUpperCase()
    ); 
  });
  return sandbox.innerHTML; 
}


const htmlCode = [
  '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">ch</span>edilpakkam,tiruvallur, chedilpakkam,tiruvallur',
  '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">ch</span> edilpakkam,tiruvallur, chedilpakkam,tiruvallur',
  '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">ch</span> edilpakkam, tiruvallur,chedilpakkam, tiruvallur',
  '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:blue;">ch</span>edilpakkam, tiruvallur,chedilpakkam, tiruvallur',
].join('<br\/>');

document.body.innerHTML = capitalizeEachTextContentWordWithinCode(htmlCode);

console.log(document.body.innerHTML.split('<br>'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 57%!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

[CheckThis](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GODXBVHQ0W3R)

```
function formatText(str) {
  var res = str.replace(/(\b[a-z])/gi, function(match, $1){
   return $1.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/^([a-z]{2})(.*)/gim, "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:Blue;'>$1</span>$2");
 return res;
}
```

Comment: You quoted it correctly. But the OP wants to achieve this task by somehow *"parsing"* a string of html code like `'<span style="font-weight:bold;color:Blue;">ch</span>edilpakkam,tiruvallur'`. Your approach takes a string like `'chedilpakkam, tiruvallur'`, does process the uppercase task and then, in a non generic process, slices exactly the first 2 letters, wraps them with a predefined html code and appends the rest of the string. Thus this approach fails if the OP wants to process code like `'<span style="color:Red;">che</span>dilpakkam,tiruvallur'` (`che` instead of `ch` and style changes).